# Why are my integers overflowing before they should?

Tags: php, php-7

I am running PHP 7.0.8 (VC14 x64 Thread Safe version) on Windows 7.

`echo PHP_INT_MAX;` shows `9223372036854775807`, but this doesn't actually seem to be correct. According to the PHP [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow),

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead.

but when I run the code from the documentation that demonstrates integer overflow on a 32-bit system, that's not what happens.

```
$large_number = 2147483647;
var_dump($large_number);     // expected: int(2147483647)     actual: int (2147483647)

$large_number = 2147483648;
var_dump($large_number);     // expected: float(2147483648)   actual: int (-2147483648)
```

Even more strangely, the other example from the docs:

```
$large_number = 9223372036854775807;
var_dump($large_number);    // expected: int(9223372036854775807)    actual: int(-1)

$large_number = 9223372036854775808;
var_dump($large_number);    
    // expected: float(9.2233720368548E+18), actual: float(9.2233720368548E+18)
```

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something? [The only similar bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72272&edit=1) I've found deals with incorrect output of `var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX)` with xdebug (which is present in my version), but that doesn't seem to explain what's happening here. If anyone knows of relevant info I should include from `phpinfo` I can add it.

Comment: Works here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a70f7c03a93c05b6583752695cacf72da7e3672

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I think it's something specific to my system, but I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting it. From what I've read, PHP on windows only started supporting 64 bit ints in PHP 7, but it appears here that my version _"thinks"_ it does while it actually doesn't.

Comment: Was able to reproduce your results on my Windows 7 machine. I installed Wamp (wampserver3.0.4_x64_apache2.4.18_mysql5.7.11_php5.6.19-7.0.4), switched it over to php7.0.4, and ran your code in a script. Didn't change any configuration options and i got your actual results. However, WAMP came with xdebug installed by default (awesome!). I added `xdebug.overload_var_dump=0` to my configuration, i got the expected output. If you don't have xdebug then, this comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @Terminus Thanks for the verification! `xdebug.overload_var_dump=0` fixes it for me as well. I think I was confused by the description in that bug report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a helpful comment from @Terminus, I tried setting `xdebug.overload_var_dump=0` in php.ini. With that setting, `var_dump` produced the correct output. It occurred to me that I had neglected to try simply `echo $large_number;` during my testing, so I turned `overload_var_dump` back on and `echo` produced the expected result while `var_dump` did not.

```
$large_number = 2147483648;
echo $large_number;                // 2147483648
var_dump($large_number);           // int -2147483648

$large_number = 9223372036854775807;
echo $large_number;                // 9223372036854775807
var_dump($large_number);           // int -1
```

So it seems that the bug report I found earlier actually does explain this. The original description in the bug report says:

> var_dump() doesn't show correct info about PHP_INT_MAX and PHP_INT_MIN constants on 64bit Windows

But it appears that this is incomplete; it actually shows incorrect info for large number variables as well as the constants.